# Why is exception is not thrown to the error-channel of the inbound when claim-check is used

Tags: spring-integration

In the error-channel attribute of message-driven-channel-adapter
I want the original inbound message as the payload not the payload at the point of failure. To achieve this I use claim-check-in/out and SimpleMessageStore. The UUID I get from claim-check-in is stored in the header of the original inbound message. This message is now consumed by the transformer and then webservice call.

When the service time out or transformation exception is thrown the error-channel of message-driven-channel-adapter does not get any message, also it seems to retry in its own infinite loop rather than throwing an exception to error-channel. Is this the expected behaviour, Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Please, share the configuration on the matter. And StackTrace when your exception is caused.

Comment: Hi Bilan, I had not given the Claim-check-id when defining the check-in and check-out, As I wont use the ID anywhere. But because of that the exception was not thrown.